# Version numbering / release mechanics with Maven and GitHub

Tags: java, git, maven, github, versioning

I'm trying to work out the optimal way of managing my workflow to allow version numbering and releases with Maven and Git.

Currently my workflow is:

1. Edit pom.xml to indicate a new snapshot version "1.2.3-SNAPSHOT"
2. Commit to git with message "start work on 1.2.3-SNAPSHOT"
3. Do coding work, commit after each successful "mvn test" etc.
4. Once happy with version, edit pom.xml version to "1.2.3"
5. Commit with message "1.2.3 Release"
6. Add a tag "1.2.3"
7. Deploy the code (e.g. push to an external Maven repository)
8. GOTO 1.

I do all the work in the "master" branch unless I need to do something experimental (in which case I switch to a new branch, merging periodically)

Is this a sensible workflow? Any ways that I could improve it.

Comment: yes: use maven-release plugin to automate your workflow (all of it!)

Comment: @Abhinav - sounds  like a promising solution - perhaps you could provide a short answer detailing the specific steps that you would take to replace the above workflow using the release plugin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [maven-release plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/) which is supposed to do that for you. Releases involve two steps:

- [`mvn release:prepare`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html) which will ask you for the released version, tag name, and next development version
- [`mvn release:perform`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/perform-mojo.html) which will build the release artifacts and publish them on a remote maven repository

To make this work, you have to configure in your pom file several things:

- proper [SCM URLs](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#SCM), which for GitHub should look like:

```
  <scm>
    <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/user/repo.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:user/repo.git</developerConnection>
    <url>https://github.com/user/repo/tree/master/</url>
  </scm>
```

- proper [distribution repositories](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Distribution_Management) where `release:perform` will upload the built artifacts

While you're at it, you should set up a GPG key that should be used for [signing tags](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-gpg-plugin/).